# Parse request returning a null JSONArray

Tags: java, android, sql, json, parse-platform

I am using parse.com as the server for an android app. I am attempting to query the parse database and get a JSON array, but unfortunately the call for the array is returning null. The following is the code on my app.

```
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
JSONArray myArray = (JSONArray) currentUser.getJSONArray("links");
System.out.println(currentUser.get("username"));
String sample = myArray.toString();
System.out.println(sample);
```

The following is a sample row from my databse on parse.

```
objectId String | username String | password String | links Array

AD5HkKpJzB           foug              (hidden)       ["like","this"]
```

My code above gets a reference to the current user. I am able to retrieve other data, say "username". Unfortunately, the "links" field returns null. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Note, the above code crashes since myArray is null.

To clarify, ParseUser is a class belonging to parse.com.

The following is my log report.

```
03-01 21:48:50.687: I/Process(22225): Sending signal. PID: 22225 SIG: 9
03-01 21:49:48.729: I/System.out(22395): foug
03-01 21:49:48.729: D/AndroidRuntime(22395): Shutting down VM
03-01 21:49:48.729: W/dalvikvm(22395): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x414a2930)
03-01 21:49:48.729: E/AndroidRuntime(22395): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-01 21:49:48.729: E/AndroidRuntime(22395): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.harris.chain/com.harris.chain.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-01 21:49:48.729: E/AndroidRuntime(22395):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2870)
03-01 21:49:48.729: E/AndroidRuntime(22395):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2899)
03-01 21:49:48.729: E/AndroidRuntime(22395):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
03-01 21:49:48.729: E/AndroidRuntime(22395):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
03-01 21:49:48.729: E/AndroidRuntime(22395):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
03-01 21:49:48.729: E/AndroidRuntime(22395):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-01 21:49:48.729: E/AndroidRuntime(22395):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-01 21:49:48.729: E/AndroidRuntime(22395):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
03-01 21:49:48.729: E/AndroidRuntime(22395):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-01 21:49:48.729: E/AndroidRuntime(22395):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-01 21:49:48.729: E/AndroidRuntime(22395):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
03-01 21:49:48.729: E/AndroidRuntime(22395):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
03-01 21:49:48.729: E/AndroidRuntime(22395):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-01 21:49:48.729: E/AndroidRuntime(22395): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-01 21:49:48.729: E/AndroidRuntime(22395):    at com.harris.chain.MainActivity.getLatestLinks(MainActivity.java:36)
03-01 21:49:48.729: E/AndroidRuntime(22395):    at com.harris.chain.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:27)
03-01 21:49:48.729: E/AndroidRuntime(22395):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1185)
03-01 21:49:48.729: E/AndroidRuntime(22395):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5182)
03-01 21:49:48.729: E/AndroidRuntime(22395):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2860)
03-01 21:49:48.729: E/AndroidRuntime(22395):    ... 12 more
```

As you can see, I am able to successfully retrieve the username "foug" from the database. But the JSONArray requests still returns null./

Comment: In you ParseUser class, you shouldn't have to use "magic strings" to it in order to retrieve the "links" JSON object. If the schema is static, write methods that fit the schema(getLinks()). 

Which JSON library are you using, and what does the JSON look like on application run time? Can you print it to the log?

Can you share the get method too?

Comment: "So you have a ParseUser class, but you're still passing "magic strings" to it in order to retrieve the "links" JSON object?" I am not really sure what this comment means. From what I understand, a SQL database doesn't actually contain "arrays", but instead has JSON objects and that parse.com is abstracting it to an array for me. The get method belongs to parse.com.

Comment: There should be a method that will return a JSONArray rather than a JSONObject, I'm trying to find their documentation.

Comment: Are you saying my column title "links" is a "magic string"? I agree that I shouldn't have hard coded text, but I still have the issue of the null array. Also, I am fairly ignorant of JSON.

Comment: Try calling currentUser.getJSONArray("links")

Yeah, hardcoding strings can get messy. You can make your own class that extends ParseUser, or create the string as a resource in strings.xml

Comment: I posted an update, unfortunately it still crashes.

Comment: Oh.. you're in onResume. Can you share the onPause code? Could it be logging out the current user? Is a user logged in?

Comment: Ok, so it appears that when I hardcoded the information into the "links" field on the parse website, it was somehow not saved. When I used my app to information to the "links" field, I was then able to retrieve said data. So now it works, I just don't know why it wasn't recognizing code I had entered from the PARSE GUI.

Comment: I am not sure how to make this solved without there being an answer. Can you close the thread/mark it resolved?

Comment: Answer the question yourself and then mark it as correct/complete. Edit the question so that it more accurately describes your problem too. I'm sure others will run into the issue and maybe they'll find this thread on google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, hardcoding data directly into Parse's database failed to actually save the data or either didn't allow me to access it from the app. Once I used the app to place data into Parse's database, I was able to retrieve the data.

Comment: Is there a way to commit from the website?